# dot product of two vectors python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble computing the dot product of two vectors in my code for the QR(matrix) portion. I'm trying to dot the result of q[i] with vector01 I don't know where my code is incorrect. Any help would be great thank you. My expected output should be sqrt(2)

```
def twoNorm(vector):
    '''
    twoNorm takes a vector as it's argument. It then computes the sum of  
    the squares of each element of the vector. It then returns the square 
    root of this sum.
    '''
    # This variable will keep track of the validity of our input.
    inputStatus = True  
    # This for loop will check each element of the vector to see if it's a number. 
    for i in range(len(vector)):  
        if ((type(vector[i]) != int) and (type(vector[i]) != float) and (type(vector[i]) != complex)):
            inputStatus = False
            print("Invalid Input")
            # If the input is valid the function continues to compute the 2-norm
            if inputStatus == True:
                result = 0
                # This for loop will compute the sum of the squares of the elements of the vector. 
                for i in range(len(vector)):
                    result = result + (vector[i]**2)
                result = result**(1/2)
            return result
    vector = [1, 0, 1]
    print(twoNorm(vector))

def QR(matrix):
    if len(matrix) != len(vector):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        qi = []
        for i in vector:
            qi.append(i/scalar)
        return qi
        if len(qi) != len(vector01):
            print('invalid input')
        else:
            total = 0
            for j in range(len(qi)):
                total += qi[j] * vector01[j]
            return total

vector01 = [2, 1, 0]   
scalar = twoNorm(vector)
vector = [1, 0, 1]
matrix = [[1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
print(QR(matrix))
```

Comment: What problems are you having, an exception, wrong output? What's your expected output?

Comment: yes the output the expected output is sqrt(2) but I'm getting an invalid answer

Comment: what is `vector` in QR function: `if len(matrix) != len(vector):`?

Comment: vector is defined at the end of the code as [1, 0, 1]

Comment: I would strongly suggest using existing Python linear algebraic functions. Numpy's linalg.norm() function can be used to compute the 2-norm (or n-norm) of any set of length 2 (or length n) vectors. Numpy's dot() function can equivalently be used to compute the dot product of any two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The two 'if' structures in your twoNorm() is incorrect(perhaps just an indent issue that you didn't notice?). Compare the code below to your code. You will find out what's wrong.

```
def twoNorm(vector):
    '''
    twoNorm takes a vector as it's argument. It then computes the sum of  
    the squares of each element of the vector. It then returns the square 
    root of this sum.
    '''
    # This variable will keep track of the validity of our input.
    inputStatus = True  
    # This for loop will check each element of the vector to see if it's a number. 
    for i in range(len(vector)):  
        if ((type(vector[i]) != int) and (type(vector[i]) != float) and (type(vector[i]) != complex)):
            inputStatus = False
            print("Invalid Input")
            # If the input is valid the function continues to compute the 2-norm
        if inputStatus == True:
            result = 0
            # This for loop will compute the sum of the squares of the elements of the vector. 
            for i in range(len(vector)):
                result = result + (vector[i]**2)
            result = result**(1/2)
            return result
```

I didn't check QR() carefully but I'm sure that it's troublesome - anything after 'return qi' won't be executed. How is QR() meant to work?